# SQL Developer "Edit User" has incomplete DDL

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm logged in as "SYS as SYSDBA" and am inspecting a user with SQL Developer 21.4.3. The user has some system privileges set:

[image: System Privileges]

But the SQL tab does not have any system privileges in the DDL:

[image: User DDL]

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit User...find a priv, CHECK (enable) it.

[image]

Then click on SQL page -
[image]

If you simply want to see EXISTING DDL for a USER including system privileges - open the DBA/Security panel.

[image]

Comment: So for system privs you're only showing things enabled in this dialogue display, not anything the user already had; but it picks up existing roles and quotas?

Comment: we're showing the code that will be executed if you hit 'OK/Apply'

Comment: That seems massively counter-intuitive, but I understand.. It's what will be executed when you click OK. What is special about the DBA/Security panel and how do I get to it?

Comment: That's how all the CREATE/EDIT dialogs work, you make gui selections, then we show the resulting code. The USER pages under DBA show you the current state of things, and the code necessary to get to that state. DBA is under VIEW menu. Once it's open, add your connection.

Comment: Hmm, OK, but it's bit confusing that it includes some things that haven't changed. The help text doesn't make that clear either - that implies it's everything after `create user`. But that's because the help is for both create and edit dialogs.

Comment: Yeah the inclusion of things that haven't changed on the other pages (like quotas) makes one believe that this should simply be the DDL for the user.

Comment: yeah there's a bug here @Jobbo we're showing code that should not be shown...i'll log that for you